# Is it possible to MMAP a PCI BAR memory?

Tags: driver, pci

I want to user access memory from a PCIe board which provides a 1GB memory with BAR0.
Currently I use only read and write functionality of my character device driver, which is VERY slow (1MB/s read and 16MB/s write) on a 8x PCIe Gen3.

```
static ssize_t
MPD_read(
    struct file *filp,
    char *buffer,
    size_t bufferSize,
    loff_t *offset )
{
    unsigned long unusedBytes = copy_to_user(
        ( void * ) buffer,
        MPD_AdapterBoard.bars[ 0 ].barHWAddress,
        bufferSize );
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t
MPD_write(
    struct file *filp,
    const char *buffer,
    size_t bufferSize,
    loff_t *offset )
{
    unsigned long unusedBytes = copy_from_user(
        MPD_AdapterBoard.bars[ 0 ].barHWAddress,
        ( void * ) buffer,
        bufferSize );
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to use the MMAP (with the .mmap file operation) to get more speed ?
Or is DMA the only option ?

Thanks in advance!

/Jesko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how it's working:

```
static int
    MPD_mmap(
    struct file *filp,
    struct vm_area_struct *vma )
{
    unsigned long offset;

    offset = vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT;
    if (( offset + ( vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start )) > MPD_AdapterBoard.bars[ 0 ].barSizeInBytes )
    {
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    offset += ( unsigned long ) MPD_AdapterBoard.bars[ 0 ].mmioStart;

    vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached( vma->vm_page_prot );

    if ( io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, offset >> PAGE_SHIFT, vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot ))
    {
        return -EAGAIN;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Attention: This is work in progress, so error checking is fairly limited.

In the hope to help someone here, the complete code can be downloaded including a test program from here: https://github.com/jesko42/minipci